# Magento index and cache. Do I need both?

Tags: magento

I am developig an import module which update product data. To speed up the process, I put index to manual mode.

```
$processes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL));
$processes->walk('save');
```

and after the import is finished, I reindex data and put index mode back to auto

```
$processes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
$processes->walk('reindexAll');
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME));
$processes->walk('save');
```

But I am not sure if I also need to clear cache. So my question is how index and cache are related. For example if I clear cache, does it also reindex all data? And on the other site, if I reindex all data, does it clear cache? Or do I need to trigger everytime both processes if I have index mode set to manual? I am not quite sure about this, I hope anybody could confirm it for sure.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magentos `System -> Cache Managment` and `System -> Index Managment` are both stand-alone features. If you rebuild such index, no matter whether thru backend or directly using `reindexAll()`, Magento will *not* automatically refresh any cache and vice versa.

The answer to `Do I need both?` (caches and indexes) is: it depends.

If you're running Magento with caches `COLLECTION_DATA` and/or `EAV` enabled, you should refresh those caches after importing and reindexing product data.

The refreshing is necessary because your importer has updated/inserted product data which the caches are not aware of, but not, because you've reindexed.

If you're running Magento with all caches disabled, you don't need both. Technically, there is no need to refresh disabled cache. Magento would be slower of course, but still be fully functional.

Comment: I am a bit confused about reindex. When is reindex necessary? From what I understand, reindex puts in database all data into one row. Magento first check for this row and if it doesn't exist, it gets data from many different tables. When you save product, it updates all tables and if reindex is enabled, also updates the row where all data is wrote for faster access. Is that correct?

Comment: You're talking about reindexing `Product Flat Data`, right? If so, yes, you're correct. Magento rebuilds all `catalog_product_flat_*` tables based on the current product EAV values when reindexing `Product Flat Data`. When you save a product while `Product Flat Data` indexer is in `MODE_MANUAL`, only the EAV tables get updated; flat tables remain untouched. Reindexing in general is necessary whenever Magento changes an indexer process status to `STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX`. If you scan the Magento source code for that constant, you can see when this happens exactly for the various indexers.

Comment: "Technically, there is no need to refresh disabled cache." - im finding even with my cache disabled its still active and i have to clear it for example to see change in product description...